# Swift MQTT Protocol implementation using mosquitto api in ios

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to implement MQTT protocol for live location updates using mosquitto api.
I have already set up the local server and in terminal message is send as well as receive well but not send in my project.
here is my code.and i am sharing the terminal screen short.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuoES.png)

```
import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT



    func mqttSetUp()
    {
        let clientID = "mosq-irTRTw6KH28CzBbUPC" //+ "tutzqscv"//String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
        let mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: "/usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf", port: 1883)
        mqtt.username = "p2"
        mqtt.password = "c1"
        mqtt.willMessage = CocoaMQTTWill(topic: "/will", message: "dieout")
        mqtt.keepAlive = 60
        mqtt.delegate = self
        mqtt.disconnect()
        mqtt.connect()
    }

    func TRACE(_ message: String = "", fun: String = #function) {
        let names = fun.components(separatedBy: ":")
        var prettyName: String
        if names.count == 2 {
            prettyName = names[0]
        } else {
            prettyName = names[1]
        }

        if fun == "mqttDidDisconnect(_:withError:)" {
            prettyName = "didDisconect"
        }
        print("[TRACE] [\(prettyName)]: \(message)")
    }
}
extension ViewController: CocoaMQTTDelegate
{
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopic topic: String)
    {
        print("topic==>\(topic)")
    }


    // Optional ssl CocoaMQTTDelegate
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        TRACE("trust: \(trust)")

        completionHandler(true)
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
        TRACE("ack: \(ack)")

        if ack == .accept {
            mqtt.subscribe("chat/room/animals/client/+", qos: CocoaMQTTQOS.qos1)
        }
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didStateChangeTo state: CocoaMQTTConnState) {
        TRACE("new state: \(state)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        TRACE("message: \(message.string!.description), id: \(id)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
        TRACE("id: \(id)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16 ) {
        TRACE("message: \(message.string!.description), id: \(id)")

        let name = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MQTTMessageNotification")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: self, userInfo: ["message": message.string!, "topic": message.topic])
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopics success: NSDictionary, failed: [String]) {
        TRACE("subscribed: \(success), failed: \(failed)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopic topics: [String]) {
        TRACE("topic: \(topics)")
    }

    func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        TRACE()
    }

    func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        TRACE()
    }

    func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
        TRACE("\(err.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Mqtt Siglton class

```
import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT

class MQTT {

    var objMQTTClient : CocoaMQTT?

    static let shared = MQTT()
    private init() {}
}
```

please create dicPayload for pass in MQTT

```
func publishMQTTMessage() {

      var dicPayload = [String : Any]()
      dicPayload["sender_id"] = <Pass Sender Id>
      dicPayload["recv_id"] = <Pass reciver Id>
      dicPayload["message"] = <message>
      dicPayload["chat_type"] = <userChatType>
      dicPayload["message_type"] = <messageType>

      MQTT.shared.MQTTPublishWithTopic(dicPayload, appDelegate.loginUser.userId, CMQTTUSERTOPIC)

 }
```

publish message with MQTT Topic

```
func MQTTPublishWithTopic(_ payload:[String : Any], _ id:Any?, _ topic : String?)
{
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payload, options: [])
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
    objMQTTClient?.publish(topic!, withString: jsonString!)
    print("message publish")

}
```

Comment: hi,
When i was call this function "message publish" but i can't call didReceiveMessage delegate method that's why i can't receive the message.

Comment: please check back end side i think issue from back end side

didReceiveMessage delegate method call when MQTT is broadcast message successfully